# How to close a tab in from a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wrote an exension which, when a website opens, fills some fields and presses the submit button.

I want to close the tab after that process.

I used the code below:

```
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id, function() { });
});
```

But it doesn't work.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What's happening after the submit button?
Do you send a message to the background?
Please note, you can close a tab from the background script.
You can call `chrome.extension.sendMessage` from a content to the background, receive `tab` object and call `chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);`